# Converting TEXT that represents NEGATIVE TIME value to a number or time value for adding (Excel)

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, negative-number

I've got a spreadsheet (Office 2007 version of Excel) full of text entries that are negative time values, example "-0:07" as in an employee took 7 mins less to complete a job than expected.  I need to perform mathematical calculations on these entries and am looking for a more elegant formula/method than I've come up with so far.

I know about 1904 date system and * or / by 24 to convert back and forth, the problem is getting a formula that will recognize the text entry as a negative time value.

I've tried value(), *1, which both work on the text fields if the number is positive, but the "-" seems to mess those up.  Even paste-special/add fails to recognize these as numbers.

Here's what I came up with that gets the job done, but it's just so ugly to me:

```
=IF(LEFT(E5,1)="-",((VALUE(RIGHT(E5,LEN(E5)-1)))*-1.0),VALUE(E5))
```

Obviously my text entry is in cell E5 in this example.

This works, so I'm not desperate for a solution, but for educational purposes (and smaller code) I'd like to know if there's a better way to this.  Does anyone have a suggestion for something shorter, easier?

Thanks.

P.S. - an interesting tidbit here, I use Excel at work, but not at home, so I uploaded a sample spreadsheet to Google Docs, and it actually handles the Value() command on those entries properly.  Weird, huh?

Thanks again for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Excel doesn't handle time spans in cells. It only deals with time. When you do "00:07" it is then converted to 0.0048611 which is the same as Jan 1st 1900 12.07 am. So if you did 2 minutes minus 7 minutes it would give at best 11.55pm.

The way you do it is the only way.